# How to split a length into a combination of sub lengths (with a list of special allowed sub lengths)

Tags: algorithm

The background is, that I need to split a drawn length into valid sub parts and while drawing I also need to snap to the next possible length.

For example I know valid part lengths are [400, 700, 1200 - 1500 in 10ths]

that would result in 3 rules:

- Rule 1: value can be 400
- Rule 2: value can be 700
- Rule 3: value can 1200, 1210, 1220, ... 1490, 1500

**Example 1**

I draw a length of 1500, I can split this in 2 ways:

- Way 1: 2x 400 + 1x 700
- Way 2: 1x 1500

**Example 2**

I draw a length of 1150, I can't split this into valid sub parts

=> no possible solutions... nearest possible length: 1100 or 1200, let's say we prefer the smaller one

1100 can only be splitted in one way

- 1x 700 + 1x 400

So I always want to find

- *1) the next best length and*
- *2) all possible combinations*

to create this length.

How would I approach to that problem to solve it? In the end I want to find out the possible ways to combine sub parts to get a total length.

**Goal:**

My goal in the end is to find the next best length and the combination with the fewest (longest) sub parts, that can be combined to this length...

Comment: `1700==400+1300`  What am I missing in your problem description ?

Comment: actually that was just a quick example... There are lengths that are not splittable into a combination of valid sub parts... But I will put in a correct example...

Comment: What is the point of posting questions with misleading examples, you're wasting your time and ours.

Comment: as the problem is, that I don't know HOW to find out the possible solutions for a given length, I am not able to control my example... there is no point in making a mistake, I just didn't see the solution... And I can't control my examples (if they really contain ALL solutions) as long as I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution: recurse. Either you apply rule 1 or you don't. So, for input 1700, either you apply rule 1 (remaining: 1300) or you don't (remaining: 1700, can't use rule 1 anymore)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, this problem is quite closely related to **Change-making problem**. Your "valid parts" are coins and your length is the total change to be given. There are a few approaches to solve this problems, dynamic-programming and greedy method among them (one may be better than the other depending on specificity of the problem.)
The Change-making problem is basically "how to get a required sum using the fewest possible amount of coins, given possible coins". It is described in many online documents.